# Can't understand small part of a MIPS assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

This program prints the ASCII characters from 0 to Z. The output is

```
0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The question is how to change the program so it prints every third ASCII character. So that the output must look like this

```
0369<?BEHKNQTWZ]
```

When I change the constant in `addi $s0,$s0,1` to `addi $s0,$s0,3`
the output is a lot of ASCII characters and it's like an infinite loop.

```
.text


main:
          li    $s0,0x30


loop:
         move   $a0,$s0     

         li $v0,11      
         syscall            

         addi   $s0,$s0,1       # what happens if the constant is changed?

          li    $t0,0x5b
         bne    $s0,$t0,loop
         nop


stop:    j       stop       
         nop
```

I don't understand the reason behind why the program goes crazy when I change that constant.

I wrote my own code as shown below which works fine and do the job but I want to understand the code above because it's an assignment.

```
 .data



 .text

        main:
              li $s0,0x30



       for: 
             addi $a0,$s0,0
             li $v0,11
             syscall
             li $t0,0x5a
             bgt $s0,$t0, done
             addi $s0,$s0,3
             j for
       done:
```

Comment: What Christian says in answer, in terms of the inner calculation: original starts with number 0x30, then increments it by 1, and loops until it does reach value 0x5b (that's 0x2b = 43 times loops). You did change the increment to 3, so you will reach values 0x33, 0x36, ..., 0x57, 0x5a, 0x5d .. jumping over the 0x5b which is being tested for equality. So the loop will exit upon `s0` will overflow one time, as that will offset the values by 1, reaching value 0x31 after some time, and from there also 0x5b. (MARS/SPIM have debuggers where you can watch this stepping instruction over intruction)

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The number of characters this prints (43) is not divisible by 3, so by adding 3 each time, your loop goes past its exit condition (s0 == t0). Try changing the `bne` to `blt`.

Your own code does exactly the same, except that it jumps out of the loop *when* it goes past the end point, rather than back to the top *unless* it has.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this helped me.